# Binary search vs sequential search

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, search

At what Array Size is it better to use the Sequential Search over the Binary Search (needs to be sorted First) for these specific situations. The first case is when all the values of the array are just random numbers and not sorted. The second case is when the values or random numbers of the array are sorted numerically from least to greatest or greatest to least. For the searches assume you are only trying to find one number in the array.

Case 1: Random numbers

Case 2: Already sorted

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Binary Search is always preferable to sequential search if the list is sorted. Maybe an exception would be if the list was only a couple elements long. If the array is not sorted binary search will not work at all

Comment: Is suggest you use a profiler and test it yourself with selected data. It really depends on the implementation of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The Sequential Search algorithm has a worst case running time of O(n) and does not depend on whether the data is sorted or not.

The Binary Search algorithm has a worst case running time of O(logn), however, in order to use algorithm the data must be sorted. If the data is not sorted, sorting the data will take O(nlogn) time.

Therefore:

Case 1: When the data is not sorted, a Sequential Search will be more time efficient as it will take O(n) time. A Binary Search would require the data to be sorted in O(nlogn) and then searched O(logn). Therefore, the time complexity would be O(nlogn) + O(logn) = O(nlogn).

Case 2: When the data is sorted, a Binary Search will be more time efficient as it will only take O(logn) time, while the Sequential Search will still take O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search is always better. But binary search always requires to array should be sorted.

Comment: Do you use binary search for 5-element array?

Comment: So you have to 1) sort it 2) use binary search  It gives longer code and `~20+n*14` operation versus `n*10` operations (loop, ifs, assignments, swaps)